# How to extract data from text columns

Tags: ruby, regex

I have two addresses side-by-side in a multi-line string:

```
 Adresse de prise en charge :                          Adresse d'arrivée :


  rue des capucines                                      rue des tilleuls


  92210       Saint Cloud                                67000            Strasbourg

  Tél.:                                                  Tél.:
```

I need to extract the addresses on the left and right with a regexp, and assign them to variables. I need to match:

- `address1`: `"rue des capucines 92210 Saint Cloud"`
- `address2`: `"rue des tilleuls 67000  Strasbourg"`

I thought of separating them with spaces, but I cant find any regexp to count the spaces. I tried:

```
en\s*charge\s*:\s*((.|\n)*)\s*
```

and similar, but that gives me both addresses, and is not what I'm looking for. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Please 1) post the input in the question as text, 2) explain what you want to match in that text.

Comment: I added a picture. But you are right, I will edit my question to be more obvious. Thank you!

Comment: Please 1) post the input in the question as text, 2) explain what you want to match in that text.

Comment: One remark: the texts are split. Perhaps, you should just read the lines, split at the middle, and then re-shuffle the odd and even chunks to get the separate addresses.

Comment: I'm sorry, edited my question also. Please do let me know if it's clearer now. ty

Comment: it's a single line, separated with spaces..

Comment: It's single multi-line string with blank lines interleaving, it's difficult to copy/paste since it will ignore the white spaces, that's why I added an image.

Comment: Why does it have to be a regular expression? It'd be more easily done without one.

Comment: Where does that string come from? The "layout" looks arbitrary.

Comment: You'll see this sort of output for a printed form. It's like a string sent to a dot-matrix printer.

Comment: Those who downvoted or voted to close may wish to consider retractions in view of the edit made by the OP to clarify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each address section in each line is indented as much as or further than the corresponding `"Adresse"` in the first line, the following can extract not only two addresses aligned sidewards, but n addresses in general.

```
lines = string.split(/#{$/}+/)
# => [
# =>   "Adresse de prise en charge :                          Adresse d'arrivée :",
# =>   "  rue des capucines                                      rue des tilleuls",
# =>   "  92210       Saint Cloud                                67000            Strasbourg",
# =>   "  Tél.:                                                  Tél.:"
# => ]

break_points = []
lines.first.scan(/\bAdresse\b/){break_points.push($~.begin(0))}
ranges = break_points.push(0).each_cons(2).map{|s, e| s..(e - 1)}
# => [0..53, 54..-1]

address1, address2 =
lines[1..-2]
.map{|s| ranges.map{|r| s[r]}}
.transpose
.map{|a| a.join(" ").strip.squeeze(" ")}
# => [
# =>   "rue des capucines 92210 Saint Cloud",
# =>   "rue des tilleuls 67000 Strasbourg"
# => ]
```

Comment: You probably want to touch up `split($/)`.

Comment: Just tried your answer and it's working! Thank you very much for all the help! :)

Comment: You just saved my day!!

Comment: `address2 = "rue des tilleul 67000 Strasbour"`, it's missing the "g" from Strasbourg.. Tried to mess around with ` ranges = break_points.push(-1)` , setting the index to other values, is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I'd do something like this:

```
str = <<EOT
Adresse de prise en charge :                          Adresse d'arrivée :


  rue des capucines                                      rue des tilleuls


  92210       Saint Cloud                                67000            Strasbourg

  Tél.:                                                  Tél.:
EOT

left_addr  = []
right_addr = []

lines = str.squeeze("\n").gsub(':', '').lines.map(&:strip) # => ["Adresse de prise en charge                           Adresse d'arrivée", "rue des capucines                                      rue des tilleuls", "92210       Saint Cloud                                67000            Strasbourg", "Tél.                                                  Tél."]
center_line_pos = lines.max.length / 2 # => 35

lines.each do |l|
  left_addr << l[0 .. (center_line_pos - 1)].strip
  right_addr << l[center_line_pos .. -1].strip
end
```

At this point `left_addr` and `right_addr` look like:

```
left_addr  # => ["Adresse de prise en charge", "rue des capucines", "92210       Saint Cloud", "Tél."]
right_addr # => ["Adresse d'arrivée", "rue des tilleuls", "67000            Strasbourg", "Tél."]
```

And here's what they contain:

```
puts left_addr
puts '------'
puts right_addr

# >> Adresse de prise en charge
# >> rue des capucines
# >> 92210       Saint Cloud
# >> Tél.
# >> ------
# >> Adresse d'arrivée
# >> rue des tilleuls
# >> 67000            Strasbourg
# >> Tél.
```

If you need the results all in one line without the 'Tel:':

```
puts left_addr[0..-2].join(' ').squeeze(' ')
puts '------'
puts right_addr[0..-2].join(' ').squeeze(' ')

# >> Adresse de prise en charge rue des capucines 92210 Saint Cloud
# >> ------
# >> Adresse d'arrivée rue des tilleuls 67000 Strasbourg
```

Here's a breakdown of what is going on:

```
str.squeeze("\n") # => " Adresse de prise en charge :                          Adresse d'arrivée :\n  rue des capucines                                      rue des tilleuls\n  92210       Saint Cloud                                67000            Strasbourg\n  Tél.:                                                  Tél.:\n"
  .gsub(':', '') # => " Adresse de prise en charge                           Adresse d'arrivée \n  rue des capucines                                      rue des tilleuls\n  92210       Saint Cloud                                67000            Strasbourg\n  Tél.                                                  Tél.\n"
  .lines         # => [" Adresse de prise en charge                           Adresse d'arrivée \n", "  rue des capucines                                      rue des tilleuls\n", "  92210       Saint Cloud                                67000            Strasbourg\n", "  Tél.                                                  Tél.\n"]
  .map(&:strip)  # => ["Adresse de prise en charge                           Adresse d'arrivée", "rue des capucines                                      rue des tilleuls", "92210       Saint Cloud                                67000            Strasbourg", "Tél.                                                  Tél."]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's not necessary to thank us, and actually the site discourages it.

Comment: What's the harm of an occasional "thank you" if it brightens the sender's or receiver's day?

Comment: The comments are part of the commentary of the Q/A process. We're answering to try to help and it's an expected part of what we do. Thanking us ends up taking up database space without adding anything useful to the commentary whereas voting up an answer as useful is more useful to the answerer. SO is a reference book, not a discussion forum, and people lose sight of that. Courtesy is expected of course, but voting up is more useful to people.

Comment: A thousand times more database space is occupied by stupid questions, stupid answers and inane comments! Brief, occasional thank yous neither distract the reader nor subvert the purpose of SO, so, I say, let them be. Nor, I would hope, should we stifle the attempts some readers make to bring smiles to our faces.

Comment: Please read the final paragraph in http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258032/128421 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272942/128421. Your opinion is understandable but it's not in line with the community's thinking.

Comment: I have no objection to the rule. I just don't think it needs enforcement, in the same way that minor traffic violations don't warrant tickets. Moreover, thank yous often contain information that may be helpful to others. For example, "Many thanks, before reading your answer answer I never understood why....". (Don't mean to belabor this, as it's really a topic for meta.)

Answer (score 2):

**Assumptions**

I have assumed that the first and last lines are not wanted and the street names are separated by at least two spaces, and the same for the postal code/city strings. This permits the street name (and postal code/city pair) for "prise en charge" to end below "Adresse d'arrivée :".

**Code**

```
def parse_text(text)  
  text.split(/\n+\s+/)[1..-2].
       map { |s| s.gsub(/\d+\K\s+/,' ').split(/\s{2,}/) }.
       transpose.
       map { |a| a.join(' ') }
end
```

**Examples**

*Example 1*

```
text = <<BITTER_END
Adresse de prise en charge :                          Adresse d'arrivée :


  rue des capucines                                      rue des tilleuls


  92210       Saint Cloud                                67000            Strasbourg

  Tél.:                                                  Tél.:
BITTER_END


parse_text(text)
  #=> ["rue des capucines 9210 Saint Cloud",
  #    "rue des tileuls 670 Strasbourg"]
```

*Example 2*

```
text = <<_
Adresse 1 :                Adresse 2 :                  Adresse 3 :


  rue nom le plus long du monde par un mile  rue gargouilles  rue des tilleuls


  92210           Saint Cloud  31400 Nice              67000     Strasbourg

  France                     France                       France

  Tél.:                      Tél.:                        Tél.:
_

parse_text(text)
  #=> ["rue nom le plus long du monde par un mile 92210 Saint Cloud France",
  #    "rue gargouilles 31400 Nice France",
  #    "rue des tilleuls 67000 Strasbourg France"]
```

**Explanation**

The steps for `text` given in the question:

Split into lines, removing blank lines and leading spaces:

```
a1 = text.split(/\n+\s+/)
  #=> ["Adresse de prise en charge :                        Adresse d'arrivée :",
  #    "rue des capucines                                    rue des tilleuls",
  #    "92210       Saint Cloud                              67000            Strasbourg",
  #    "Tél.:                                                Tél.:\n"]
```

Remove first and last lines:

```
a2 = a1[1..-2]
  #=> ["rue des capucines                                    rue des tilleuls",
  #    "92210       Saint Cloud                              67000            Strasbourg"]
```

Remove extra spaces between the postal codes and cities and split each line on two or more spaces:

```
r = /
    \d+  # match one or more digits
    \K   # forget everything matched so far
    \s+  # match one of more spaces
    /x   # extended/free-spacing regex definition mode 

a3 = a2.map { |s| s.gsub(/\d+\K\s+/,' ').split(/\s{2,}/) }
  #=> [["rue des capucines", "rue des tilleuls"],
  #    ["92210 Saint Cloud", "67000 Strasbourg"]]
```

Group by column:

```
a4 = a3.transpose
  #=> [["rue des capucines", "92210 Saint Cloud"],
  #    ["rue des tilleuls", "67000 Strasbourg"]]
```

Join strings:

```
a4.map { |a| a.join(' ') }
  #=> ["rue des capucines 92210 Saint Cloud",
  #    "rue des tilleuls 67000 Strasbourg"]
```

Comment: Watch out. Simply using `squeeze` has danger of applying that to any consecutive characters that may possibly appear. And in fact, you got the wrong answer because of that.

Comment: Thanks, @sawa. I fixed that and made some other changes. Our answers may be converging.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = 
" Adresse de prise en charge :                          Adresse d'arrivée :


  rue des capucines                                      rue des tilleuls


  92210       Saint Cloud                                67000            Strasbourg

  Tél.:                                                  Tél.:"

adr_prise, adr_arr = str.lines[3].strip.split(/ {2,}/) #split on 2+ spaces
code_prise, cite_prise, code_arr, cite_arr = str.lines[6].strip.split(/ {2,}/)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [@steenslag's very pragmatic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35231752/179125), here's a pretty dense one-liner just for fun.

```
# Assume the input data is in the variable `text`
left_addr, right_addr = text.lines.values_at(3, 6).map do |line|
    line.scan(/(?:\d+  +)?\S+(?: \S+)*/)
        .map {|part| part.squeeze(' ') }
  end
  .transpose
  .map {|addr| addr.join(' ') }

puts left_addr
# => rue des capucines 92210 Saint Cloud
puts right_addr
# => rue des tilleuls 67000 Strasbourg
```

Like @steenslag's answer, this assumes that the desired data is always on lines 3 and 6. It also assumes that on line 6 both columns will have a postal code and city and that the postal code will always start with a digit.

Because it's a pretty dense one-liner and because it makes a lot of assumptions, I don't think this is the best answer and I'm marking it Community Wiki.

If I have time I'll come back and unpack this later.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the "center line position" is known, this would work:

```
left_lines, right_lines = str.scan(/^(.{50})(.*)$/).transpose
```

The regular expression captures 50 characters at the beginning of each line plus the remaining characters until the line's end.

[`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-scan) returns a nested array: (I'm using placeholders because the actual lines are too long)

```
[
  ['1st left line', '1st right line'],
  ['2nd left line', '2nd right line'],
  ...
]
```

[`transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) converts it to:

```
[
  ['1st left line', '2nd left line', ...],    # <- assigned to left_lines
  ['1st right line', '2nd right line', ...]   # <- assigned to right_lines
]
```

The lines (excluding the first and last line) have to be [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-join)ed and spaces have to be removed: (see [`strip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-strip) and [`squeeze`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-squeeze))

```
left_lines[1..-2].join(' ').strip.squeeze(' ')
#=> "rue des capucines 92210 Saint Cloud"
```

Same for `right_lines`:

```
right_lines[1..-2].join(' ').strip.squeeze(' ')
#=> "rue des tilleuls 67000 Strasbourg"
```

Comment: This assumes there is a "center line". It looks like there is one, but we don't know what happens if the street name in the first group is so long that it would end below the second column label (if not truncated). It may be better to simply assume that the street names are separated by at least two spaces and the same for the postal code/city strings. If you want to keep the center line approach, better to compute it (e.g., `arr = text.lines; i = arr.max_by(&:size).max.times.find { |i| arr[i,2] == '  ' }`.